# Does Digital Certificate affect privacy of the user?

Tags: certificates

As I know the user use the digital certificate to identify himself for the others. Can a Digital Certificate to be use as unique identifier for the user to trace and profile user activities?

Comment: Who would be doing the tracing and profiling? How are the certificates used in your scenario?

Comment: What @schroeder says is an *important* starting point. Whom are your adversaries? Different adversaries may have different goals (e.g. infiltration, data theft, surveilance or destruction), and different techniques work against different scenarios. Public, but very valuable data, is different from not-so-valuable, but **highly** confidential data.

Comment: My big concern is privacy, when the mobile node move between networks and this certificate sends every time join network. Can attackers or adversaries to trace the client?

Comment: Privacy from *whom*? Network administrator/owner? Other people on the network? Passive eavesdropping? Active fingerprinting?

Answer (score 1):

You don't define your adversaries.

Certificates can be used to authenticate users, much in the same fashion (albeit more secure) as passwords.

For instance you may use PKI to authenticate your self to the bank, and the browser may use it for every request. In that case the bank has essentially zero chance of confusing two users, even if they swap IP's or other characteristics.

On the other hand, someone reading the encrypted traffic over the wire would optimally not be able to learn anything about the communication. Some information will leak from metadata, such as source and destination IP's.

Put simply certificates are a tool to authenticate resources, be it users or server.

Answer (score -2):

Digital certificates are used as signatures to send an encoded message and a method to send a reply.

> "...the private key used to 'sign' a digital signature is not used by
>   the recipient to verify the signature, [and] digital signatures are
>   not easily subverted by replay attacks." (O'Reilly)

These signatures are only used once, and are not traceable.

Comment: You do not appear to understand what a digital certificate is. Also, when citing a source, it is important not to only cite the publisher, but the actual source. O'Reilly produces a LOT of books ...